# how do I serialize a xml node in c#

Tags: c#, asp.net, serialization, xml-serialization

I have a xml node.

```
      <Region Region_Sequence="1" Region_Name="Vadodra" Region_Code="VAD"/>
```

how can I serialize this xmlnode to my region class
using c# and asp.net

Comment: use `Miscrosoft.Serialization` class

Comment: What is the definition of your Region class? What have you tried so far?

Answer (score 1):

You can do the following:

```
using System.Xml.Linq;

namespace XMLParser
{
    class ParseXML
    {
     public void ParseXML(string strXML)
{
XDocument xdoc = XDocument.Load(strXML);
var region= from regions in xdoc.Element("Region");

Region objRegion=new Region();
Region.Region_Name=region.Element("Region_Name").Value.ToString();
}
}

}
```

Answer (score 0):

Something like this:

```
string xml = "<Region Region_Sequence=\"1\" Region_Name=\"Vadodra\" Region_Code=\"VAD\"/>"

var serializer = new XmlSerializer(typeof(Region));
Region result;

using (TextReader reader = new StringReader(xml))
{
    result = (Region)serializer.Deserialize(reader);
}
```